# Pandas DF Filter if all values in row equal False

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a DF of bool values. I'd like to select the row which have a False value in all of the columns. I've tried a few variations but so far nothing.

My latest attempt is:

```
example_data != True
```

When I run this I seem the entire df returned.

I'm sure this is a simple thing that I either don't know or have forgotten about filtering.

Any direction on getting a fix is welcome :)

**Example Data**

```
example_data = {'Meta_Description_contains_kw': 97     False
 99     False
 100    False
 101    False
 480    True 
 537    True 
 549    True 
 116    False
 120    False
 121    False
 482    True 
 123    True 
 125    False
 129    False
 550    False
 131    False
 593    True 
 136    False
 138    False
 140    False
 141    False
 143    False
 16     True 
 152    False
 157    False
 158    False
 160    False
 175    False
 594    True 
 186    False
 194    False
 605    False
 197    False
 488    True 
 525    True 
 202    False
 585    True 
 207    False
 493    False
 634    True 
 642    True 
 231    False
 498    True 
 619    False
 510    False
 50     False
 512    False
 Name: Meta_Description_contains_kw, dtype: bool,
 'Title_1_contains_kw': 97     False
 99     False
 100    False
 101    False
 480    True 
 537    True 
 549    True 
 116    False
 120    False
 121    False
 482    True 
 123    True 
 125    False
 129    False
 550    False
 131    False
 593    True 
 136    False
 138    False
 140    False
 141    False
 143    False
 16     True 
 152    False
 157    False
 158    False
 160    False
 175    False
 594    True 
 186    False
 194    False
 605    False
 197    False
 488    True 
 525    True 
 202    False
 585    True 
 207    False
 493    False
 634    True 
 642    True 
 231    False
 498    True 
 619    False
 510    False
 50     False
 512    False
 Name: Title_1_contains_kw, dtype: bool,
 'H1-1_contains_kw': 97     False
 99     False
 100    False
 101    False
 480    True 
 537    True 
 549    True 
 116    False
 120    False
 121    False
 482    True 
 123    True 
 125    False
 129    False
 550    False
 131    False
 593    True 
 136    False
 138    False
 140    False
 141    False
 143    False
 16     True 
 152    False
 157    False
 158    False
 160    False
 175    False
 594    True 
 186    False
 194    False
 605    False
 197    False
 488    True 
 525    True 
 202    False
 585    True 
 207    False
 493    False
 634    True 
 642    True 
 231    False
 498    True 
 619    False
 510    False
 50     False
 512    False
 Name: H1-1_contains_kw, dtype: bool,
 'H2-1_contains_kw': 97     False
 99     False
 100    False
 101    False
 480    True 
 537    True 
 549    True 
 116    False
 120    False
 121    False
 482    False
 123    True 
 125    False
 129    False
 550    False
 131    False
 593    True 
 136    False
 138    False
 140    False
 141    False
 143    False
 16     True 
 152    False
 157    False
 158    False
 160    False
 175    False
 594    True 
 186    False
 194    False
 605    False
 197    False
 488    False
 525    True 
 202    False
 585    False
 207    False
 493    False
 634    False
 642    True 
 231    False
 498    False
 619    False
 510    False
 50     False
 512    False
 Name: H2-1_contains_kw, dtype: bool,
 'H2-2_contains_kw': 97     False
 99     False
 100    False
 101    False
 480    True 
 537    False
 549    True 
 116    False
 120    False
 121    False
 482    False
 123    True 
 125    False
 129    False
 550    False
 131    False
 593    False
 136    False
 138    False
 140    False
 141    False
 143    False
 16     True 
 152    False
 157    False
 158    False
 160    False
 175    False
 594    False
 186    False
 194    False
 605    False
 197    False
 488    False
 525    False
 202    False
 585    False
 207    False
 493    False
 634    True 
 642    False
 231    False
 498    False
 619    False
 510    False
 50     False
 512    False
 Name: H2-2_contains_kw, dtype: bool}
```

Comment: please provide data in a readable format (executable code, creating a minimal example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with inverted all columns by `~` and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[(~df).all(axis=1)]
#if want seelct only boolean columns
df = df[(~df.select_dtypes(bool)).all(axis=1)]
print (df.head())
     Meta_Description_contains_kw  Title_1_contains_kw  H1-1_contains_kw  \
50                          False                False             False   
97                          False                False             False   
99                          False                False             False   
100                         False                False             False   
101                         False                False             False   

     H2-1_contains_kw  H2-2_contains_kw  
50              False             False  
97              False             False  
99              False             False  
100             False             False  
101             False             False
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this`example_data=example_data[example_data!=True]`

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think this pseudo code can help you with the logic.

```
for column in df.columns:
    if df[column].dtype == bool and not any(df[column]):
            print('The column `%s` has all false values'%column)
```

basically Iterated over all column and checked if type is bool.
and when type is book i applied `any` function to that column, it will return True if any True value else return False.

Answer (score 1):

Recall True = 1 & False = 0.

Sum across your row values. If the sum(bools) = 0, then they're all false. If sum(bools) = num_columns, then they're all true.

```
series_sums = numpy.sum(dataframe, axis=1) # sum across columns
series_all_true = numpy.equal(series_sums, dataframe.shape[1])
series_all_false = numpy.equal(series_sums, 0)
```

You could use `dataframe.sum(axis = 1)` and call equality directly, but numpy handles weird errors like string comparisons & nans better.

```
series_sums = dataframe.sum(axis=1) # sum across columns
series_all_true = series_sums == dataframe.shape[1]
series_all_false = series_sums == 0
```

Finally, recall a boolean series is called a "mask", and you can use masks to select the rows you want.

```
dataframe_false_rows = dataframe[series_all_false]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
example_data = example_data.loc[!(column1 & column2 &.....)]
```

I think this will do the trick (assuming example_data is the variable name of your dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by transposition (twice).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, True, False, False], 'B': [True, False, True, False]})

df[df.T.all().T]
```